# Using TypeDefinition in ElementMatchers.takesArguments()

Tags: byte-buddy

I am creating a class like this:

```
class A{
  A(A a){
   ...
  }
 

  A(){
    A(null);
  }
}
```

and my code looks like this:

```
TypeDefinition selfTypeDefinition = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.rawType(TargetType.class).build();

Class c = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class,ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS).name("A").
                defineConstructor(Modifier.PUBLIC).withParameters(selfTypeDefinition)
                .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Object.class.getConstructor())
                        .andThen(MethodCall.run(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println("!!!!init A(A)");
                            }
                        })))
                .defineConstructor(Modifier.PUBLIC).withParameters(new Type[0])
                .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(ElementMatchers.isConstructor()
                         .and(ElementMatchers.takesArguments(selfTypeDefinition)))
                        .with(new Object[1])
                        .andThen(MethodCall.run(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println("!!!!init A()");
                            }
                        })))
                .make().load(Test.class.getClassLoader()).getLoaded();
```

The problem is I cannot pass TypeDefinition to ElementMatchers.takesArguments(). I have tried passing selfTypeDefinition.asErasure() but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `selfTypeDefinition.asErasure()` to represent a `TypeDescription`. Byte Buddy also supports matching generic type descriptions, but the matcher you are using expects an erasure format.

Comment: I tried it but when I use asErasure() it gives me this error during the make() method. `class A does not define exactly one virtual method or constructor for (isConstructor() and hasParameter(hasTypes(erasures(containing(is(class net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TargetType)))))) but contained 0 candidates: []`

Comment: I was able to fix it by defining `TypeDescription.Generic g = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.rawType(Object.class).build();
        InstrumentedType instrumentedType = InstrumentedType.Default.of("A", g, Modifier.PUBLIC);` and using `instrumentedType` instead of `TypeDescription.Generic selfTypeDefinition` but here is my question, is it valid to use InstrumentedType in this way instead of 'TypeDescription.Generic selfTypeDefinition' ? because I don't know what is their difference and what each type really do

Comment: Hmm, could you create a reproducer and post it to Github?